# How to perform group by on datatable field with relationship define between 2 datatables?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am having 2 datatables with following records in **dataset**:

**dtVariant:**

```
Name        Type        status
Variant1    Add          active
Variant2    Division     active
```

**dtSubVariant:**

```
Name       Type           SubvariantName 
Variant1    Add            Sub1
Variant1    Add            Sub2
Variant1    Add            Sub3
Variant2    Division       Sub1
Variant2    Division       Sub2
Variant2    Division       sub3
Variant2    Division       sub4
```

Now I want to get **Subvariants List by variant Type** and only those variants whose status is active like below:

```
Add:Sub1,Sub2,Sub3

Division:Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,Sub4
```

Here I have build the relationship between Columns `Name and Type` between this 2 datatables like below:

```
Ds1.Relations.Add("MyRelation", dtVariant, dtSubVariant, false);
```

**Query**:

```
var data = (from c in Ds1.Tables["dtVariant"].AsEnumerable()
   .where c.Field<string>("status")=="active"
           group c by new { Type = c.Field<string>("Type") } into grp       
           select new
           {
                 Type= grp.Key.Type,
                  Names=
               from dp in c.GetChildRows("MyRelation")//Not getting this method
           }).ToList();
```

But when I am trying to do this:

```
from dp in c.GetChildRows("MyRelation") //i am not getting this GetChildRows method.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = Ds1.Tables["dtSubVariant"].AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(i => i.Type)
             .select(x=>new
                   {
                    Type= i.Key.Type,
                    SubVariantList=i.Select(x=>x.SubvariantName).ToArray()
                   }).ToList();
```

You have all info in `dtSubVariant`, and you can use this query to get it.

Comment: I have updated my question with some change.forgotten to include status field.sorry

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is what linq was built for ...

```
var result = Ds1.Tables["dtVariant"].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.Type);
```

Comment: Updated my question. Forgotten to include status field in variant datatable.sorry

Comment: My answer hasn't changed because based on the question this is still the solution, oyu may want to add a where clause after the AsEnumerable() but this still solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you are setting your relation properly, but it might be a bit faster without it:

```
string[] activeTypes = Ds1.Tables["dtVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => r["status"] == "active").Select(r => r["Type"] + "").ToArray();

var data = Ds1.Tables["dtSubVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["Type"] + "")
    .Where(g => activeTypes.Contains(g.Key))
    .Select(g => new { 
        Type = g.Key,
        Names = g.ToList()
    }).ToList();
```